# Merging two dataframes creates more rows than original data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I would like to combined two data frames into one table. In such a way that the column `a` is common to both data frames. I made a simple example with the merge function:

My code:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:100,100,replace = FALSE), b = sample(LETTERS[1:20],100,replace = TRUE), 
                  x= rep(month.abb[1:10],10,replace = TRUE), y=rep(rownames(mtcars[10:19,]),10))
df1 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:100,50,replace = FALSE), b = sample(LETTERS[1:20],50,replace = TRUE), 
                  x= rep(month.abb[1:10],5,replace = TRUE), y=rep(rownames(mtcars[10:19,]),5))

head(merge(df1,df2, by="a"))
   a b.x x.x                y.x b.y x.y                 y.y
1  1   R Oct        Honda Civic   S Jul Lincoln Continental
2  3   R May        Merc 450SLC   S Mar          Merc 450SE
3  5   S Jun Cadillac Fleetwood   T Feb           Merc 280C
4  8   T Feb          Merc 280C   P Apr          Merc 450SL
5 11   B Oct        Honda Civic   B Apr          Merc 450SL
6 12   H Mar         Merc 450SE   H Sep            Fiat 128
```

The code works fine for this data. But I have hundreds of observations and after using the above code I get a lot more observations than in the original data. I searched many solutions and didn't find the right one, each time the merge creates too much observations. I understand that the rows to duplicate, but I do not know how to fix it. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for an inner join?

Comment: Do you need an inner join instead of full join ? Also `df1` and `df2` are already dataframes so no need for `as.data.frame`. Try `merge(df1, df2, by='Name')`

Comment: I try `merge(df1, df2, by='Name')` and I get error: Join results in 3529 rows; more than 1680 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again.

Comment: I'm not sure, what exactly you are after. It would help if you included an example that actually shows the problem you are having as well as the expected result. 
After consulting my crystal ball I think you may want to look at the `all`, `all.x` and `all.y` options to `merge` – but I may be wrong.

Comment: Ok, I change my data. Matching should only take place after column `a`.